# Converted a .tex into pdf by mistake in TexStudio

Tags: pdf, texstudio

I saved a .tex file as a pdf with TexStudio. It has made a weird conversion and I was hoping to recover my original .tex file by saving it back as a pdf. However I now have this when I open it in TexStudio.

[image]

Is there a way to recover my original file ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: that is a pdf file not tex, do not edit in a text editor. If you view the file in  pdf viewer you should recover the text but the tex markup has gone. check if you have a backup

Comment: A file with .tex externsion is plain text file. I you "save as" with the .pdf extension is still  a plain text file, but this seems a true PDF, i.e., an exported version via LaTeX. That export never delete the latex source. Maybe you still have the source .tex version  in your working directory (check the extensions !) or somewhere (check if you moved it to a wrong directory, send it to trash with auxiliary  files, etc.)